# Python LTSM Value error during model prediction "Feature names seen at fit time, yet now missing"

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, prediction

I have data with dependent variables (stock price) and various independent variables, I want to build an RNN model that is trained on training data and continue to learn as soon as I have additional data update the parameters, and provide me a projected path for next 10 future entries, the path be calculated using Monte Carlo simulation and also display my expected shortfall and VaR.

But I am experiencing the below error when I call the function. But the I have similar features in the new_data, which is prediction data as I had in the model fit. I could not resolve this issue.

**predictions = predictor.predict(prediction_data, n_steps=10)**

**ValueError: The feature names should match those that were passed during fit.
Feature names seen at fit time, yet now missing: -stockprice**

```
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np

class StockPredictor:
    def __init__(self, training_data, independent_vars, epochs=100):
        self.scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
        self.training_data = training_data
        self.independent_vars = independent_vars
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.build_model()

    def build_model(self):
        # Prepare training data
        features = self.training_data[self.independent_vars]
        targets = self.training_data["stockprice"]
        scaled_data = self.scaler.fit_transform(features.join(targets))
        sequences = self.create_sequences(scaled_data)
        x_train, y_train = self.split_sequences(sequences)

        # Build RNN model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
        model.add(LSTM(units=50))
        model.add(Dense(1))
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

        # Train model
        model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=self.epochs, verbose=1)

        self.model = model

    def create_sequences(self, data, seq_length=50):
        sequences = []
        for i in range(len(data) - seq_length):
            seq = data[i:i + seq_length]
            sequences.append(seq)
        return np.array(sequences)


    def split_sequences(self, sequences, split_ratio=0.8):
        split_index = int(len(sequences) * split_ratio)
        x_train, y_train = sequences[:split_index, :-1], sequences[:split_index, -1]
        return x_train, y_train

    def predict(self, new_data, n_steps=10):
        # Separate features and target
        features = new_data[self.independent_vars]
        target = new_data["stockprice"]

        # Scale features and target separately
        scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
        scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(features)
        scaled_target = scaler.fit_transform([[target]])
        #scaled_features = self.scaler.transform(features.values.reshape(1, -1))
        #scaled_target = self.scaler.transform([[target]])

        # Combine scaled features and target for prediction
        scaled_data = np.concatenate((scaled_features, scaled_target), axis=1)

        # Create sequence for prediction
        sequence = scaled_data[-n_steps:]
        sequence = self.create_sequences(sequence)

        # Predict next n steps
        predictions = []
        for _ in range(n_steps):
            prediction = self.model.predict(sequence)[0][0]
            predictions.append(prediction)

            # Update sequence for multi-step prediction (optional)
            # new_seq = np.append(sequence, prediction)[1:]
            # new_seq[-1] = scaled_target
            # sequence = new_seq

        # Inverse transform predictions and target
        predictions = self.scaler.inverse_transform(np.array([predictions]))[0]
        target = self.scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_target)[0][0]

        # Return predictions and target
        return predictions, target
    

    def monte_carlo_simulation(self, n_samples=1000):
        # Predict next 10 steps with different noise
        simulations = []
        for _ in range(n_samples):
            noise = np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=10)
            prediction = self.predict(self.training_data[-1]) + noise
            simulations.append(prediction)

        return np.array(simulations)

    def get_risk_measures(self, simulations):
        # Calculate expected shortfall (ES)
        es = simulations[np.percentile(simulations, 5)]

        # Calculate VaR at 95% confidence level
        var = simulations[np.percentile(simulations, 95)]

        # Calculate probability of upward/downward movement
        upward_probability = np.mean(simulations[-1] > simulations[0])
        downward_probability = 1 - upward_probability

        return es, var, upward_probability, downward_probability

    def update_model(self, new_data):
        # Add new data to training data
        self.training_data = self.training_data.append(new_data)


training_data = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/xx/Desktop/xxxx.xlsx", sheet_name='Training')
independent_vars = ['feature1','feature2']

new_data =  pd.read_excel("C:/Users/xx/Desktop/xxxx.xlsx", sheet_name='Testing')

predictor = StockPredictor(training_data, independent_vars)

relevant_features = ['stockprice','feature1','feature2']


prediction_data = new_data[relevant_features]

predictions = predictor.predict(prediction_data, n_steps=10)

predictions = predictor.predict(new_data, n_steps=10)
simulations = predictor.monte_carlo_simulation(n_samples=1000)
es, var, upward_prob, downward_prob = predictor.get_risk_measures(simulations)

predictor.update_model(new_data)


print(f"Predictions: {predictions}")
print(f"Expected shortfall: {es:.2f}")
print(f"VaR (95%): {var:.2f}")
print(f"Upward probability: {upward_prob:.2%}")
print(f"Downward probability: {downward_prob:.2%}")
```